# Как в C# CefSharp по клике на кнопку открыть другой url

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Питаюсь сделать браузер. Поставил CefSharp все работает, программа запускается и открывается сайт. Теперь питаюсь сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопку открылся какой либо другой сайт но не могу найти в поиске гугл как это сделать. Поэтому пишу тут.
Кто знает помогите пожалуйста.

Сейчас имею такое.

```xml
<Window x:Class="CefSharpApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CefSharpApp"
        xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="900">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Открит  сайт - 1" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" />
        <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Browser_Test"  Address="https://2ip.ru/" />
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CefSharpApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала можно попробовать вот так

```xml
<Button ... Click="Button_Click"/>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Browser_Test.Address = "https://ya.ru";
}
```

Comment: Работает. Спасибо. Оказалось так просто. Я и не ожидал.
Если знаете, как подскажите. Как проверить загрузилась ли полностью страница?

Comment: @AnatolyDev почитайте документацию по CEF, или по CefSharp, там всё есть.